# Adding objects to arrayList using a CSV file, but the values of the objects are returning null

Tags: java, csv, object, arraylist

I'm trying to use a CSV file to create a list of employee objects, but I'm currently getting null for every value. The values being: username, firstname, lastname, email, gender, race, id, and ssn. I can read in the CSV file and parse it fine, but when I try to populate the list with the objects, It fills them but every value is still null. The main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String csvFile = "employee_data.csv";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";
    List<Entry> People = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            // use comma as separator
            String[] Labels = line.split(cvsSplitBy);                 
            Entry entry = new Entry(Labels[0], Labels[1], Labels[2], Labels[3], Labels[4], Labels[5], Labels[6], Labels[7]);
            People.add(entry);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.print(People);
}
```

The Entry class:

```
public class Entry {
    private String Username, Firstname, Lastname, Email, Gender, Race, ID, SSN;
    public Entry(String Username, String Firstname, String Lastname, String Email, String Gender, String Race, String ID, String SSN) {
        this.Username=null;
        this.Firstname=null;
        this.Lastname=null;
        this.Email=null;
        this.Gender=null;
        this.Race=null;
        this.ID=null;
        this.SSN=null;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ("Username:"+this.Username);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why the Entry objects are being properly added to the List, but the values from the Labels array is not being transferred, so username, firstname, etc are all being labeled null and I cant figure out why

Comment: Why are you surprised? You assign `null` to every field in your constructor: `this.Username=null; this.Firstname=null; ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the constructor on your Entry class needs to assign the parameters to the fields in your class.  How about the following:

```
public class Entry {

    private String Username, Firstname, Lastname, Email, Gender, Race, ID, SSN;

    public Entry(String Username, String Firstname, String Lastname, String Email, String Gender, String Race, String ID, String SSN) {
        this.Username = Username;
        this.Firstname = Firstname;
        this.Lastname = Lastname;
        this.Email = Email;
        this.Gender = Gender;
        this.Race = Race;
        this.ID = ID;
        this.SSN = SSN;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ("Username:" + this.Username);
    }
}
```